# Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react-native'

Tags: react-native, webpack, webpack-dev-server, babel-loader, react-native-web

I have recently integrated `react-native-web` into my native project and have included webpack. I've followed all the instructions listed [here](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/?path=/docs/guides-multi-platform--page).
However, when trying to run using the webpack command listed on the bottom of that page, i keep getting the error:

```
ERROR in ./index.web.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react-native' from '<*path to root*>'
```

I have the preset `metro-react-native-preset` already installed and my babel config looks like  the following:

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset']
};
```

Im currently using React Native 0.62

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to install 'babel-preset-react-native'?

```
npm install --save -dev babel-preset-react-native
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i was under the assumption the `babel-preset-react-native` has been deprecated and with `metro-react-native-babel-preset` so should i really be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You said you've got `metro-react-native-preset` already installed but your config has `metro-react-native-babel-preset` - I assume that mismatch is just accidental?

Anyway, that's probably unrelated. Here's a few things to try:

1. Have you verified you've got 0.62 of react native installed? I.e. in the npm lock file, as maybe you're on an older version (pre 0.57) which uses that older plugin.
2. Have you got a `.babelrc` file too, perhaps, with the other plugin defined instead?
3. Similar to (1), have you tried to delete the lock file and/or node_modules folder and run `npm install` again from scratch so versions match up properly.